# Does there exist a graph $G$ so that, for the Petersen Graph $P$ and the line graph operator $L$, $L(G)=P$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let the Petersen Graph be denoted $P$. Let the line graph operator be denoted $L$ so that for a graph $G$, $L(G)$ is the line graph of $G$. Does there exist a graph $G$ so that $L(G)=P$? Justify your claim.

The work I've done has been an attempt at brute forcing. The algorithm I followed was:

1. Orient the Petersen Graph so that it has 5 "outer" vertices and 5 "inner" vertices.
2. Choose an "outer" vertex of $P$; draw it as an edge in $G$, and use the arbitrarily drawn vertices in $G$ to draw all adjacent edges (or connected vertices from $P$).
3. Continue until all "outer" vertices of $P$ are represented as edges in $G$.

I truncated the algorithm as I did because I could not find any way to properly draw all the adjacent edges for $G$ so that they represented the connected vertices of $P$. So I would like to claim that $G$ does not exist, or so I am under the influence of thinking. The problem then becomes formalizing (again, assuming I am correct in saying no such $G$ exists).

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

A line graph cannot contain a claw as an induced subgraph; the central vertex would correspond to an edge $e$ incident to exactly three other edges in the original graph $G$, but pigeonholing forces a degree-$\ge3$ vertex incident to $e$ and hence a triangle in $L(G)$ where the putative *induced* claw is. Since the Petersen graph has such an induced claw, it is not a line graph.

Comment: How can anything be **far** simpler than observing that a line graph must be claw-free, because an edge of a graph can't be adjacent to $3$ independent edges, because the edge has only $2$ endvertices?

Comment: That is a very great answer! Thank you!